# Error to compile

Tags: errors, winedt

I am using WinEdt to compile a LaTeX file and I obtain the following error when I click in "TeXify" (the bear)

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.6.29)
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `-c-style-errors'.
<*>  -c-style-errors
```

Is `-c-style-errors` a file I should have? Where can I get it?

It compiles well if I click on "LaTex" ...

Comment: It's not a file, it looks like a parameter (that has to do with how errors are displayed). Apparently the configuration of the TeXify command is not fully correct, the parameter is probably not in the right position in the command specification. You can check the _Execution Modes_ dialog in WinEdt to see which switches and parameters are set, compare the different compilers, and see if you can spot the mistake in the configuration. If not then you can add some information from that dialog here in your question, maybe somebody here knows what the problem is when they see the configuration.

Comment: Thank you Marijn, I was trying different things in the Execution Modes dialog and now I get a different warning::""entering extended mode
! I can't find file `C:/Sergio(30-06-2020)/TESIS'.
<*>  C:/Sergio(30-06-2020)/TESIS
                                 Y ARTIC/Grafos/Indices Topologicos/VDB topo...
Please type another input file name: " I seems it cannot find my file .....if I write the name of the file, it compiles without error but it does not show the Dvi directly